# Should this question be closed or answered?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1160354/320386) concerns running minikube, a Kubernetes VM based on VirtualBox. The OP is experiencing the error as minikube can't be run on a nested VM (Windows, running Ubuntu on Vbox, runnin minikube). This is something that may be developed in future as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4530).

It feels like I should maybe VTC as bug report/feature request, but also that the correct answer is "You can't do that yet", which may be useful for other users?

Should I vote to close or answer?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is a bug report, as they are simply stating they have this issue and it's a known issue already reported upstream and already indicated as "Not Supported" (*which is an answer!*) nor is the question offtopic so I would say the two proper things to do are either **answer the question** or **do nothing** (but it sounds like this second option is NOT what you want to do).

Save the close votes for actual things that need closed - actual not-questions, unclear questions, offtopic questions, etc.

Comment: I'd thought answering was the way to go, but doubting myself. Cheers for clearing that up.